# change GC in quarkus jib build docker container

Tags: garbage-collection, quarkus, jib

How can the default GC be changed in quarkus docker image using jib as building engine?

I have tried with settings in application.yaml but got duplicate gc defined error as using the following parameter it writes the parameters to JAVA_OPTS env variable

```
quarkus.jib.jvm-additional-arguments: -XX:+UseZGC,-XX:+ZGenerational
```

and the jvm command in docker already has this which is there by default using JIB

```
java -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80.0 -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=10 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=20 -XX:GCTimeRatio=4 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=90 -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -cp . -jar /home/jboss/quarkus-run.jar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are seeing such behavior is because the default base image used by `quarkus-container-image-jib` is `registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/openjdk...` which uses [this](https://github.com/jboss-container-images/openjdk/blob/ubi8/modules/run/artifacts/opt/jboss/container/java/run/run-java.sh) script to determine the JVM launch params.

You can take a look [here](https://jboss-container-images.github.io/openjdk/ubi8/ubi8-openjdk-17.html) to see all the options you can set that influence the script.
The environment variable that influnces the GC used is `GC_CONTAINER_OPTIONS`, so the first thing you need to do is:

```
quarkus.jib.environment-variables.GC_CONTAINER_OPTIONS=-XX:+UseZGC
```

If you additionally want to use Generational ZGC, you need to also configure

```
quarkus.jib.jvm-additional-arguments=-XX:+ZGenerational
```

Using two different syntaxes is definitely clunky, so I have opened [this](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/39783) issue to improve the situation.